# Django 3.2.5 read-only DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get to show the creation date of a model inside the Django administration, but everytime I use auto_now_add, it disappears from the user (superuser) view.

In models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
readonly_fields=('creation_date', 'modified')
project_id = models.UUIDField(
     primary_key = True,
     default = uuid.uuid4,
     editable = False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=datetime.now) #This is what I want to show
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=datetime.now)          #I also want to show this one
start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

# Orders the projects by date
class Meta:
    ordering = ['start_date']


def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.brand.customer.name, self.name)
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Customer, Project, Brand, Supplier, Quotation, Expense


admin.site.register(Customer)
admin.site.register(Brand)
admin.site.register(Project)
admin.site.register(Supplier)
admin.site.register(Quotation)
admin.site.register(Expense)
```

Comment: Share your `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: This may or may not be related, but auto_now_add and auto_now don't accept functions - they accept booleans, and if they are set to `True`, then the current time/date is automatically used.

Comment: @pigrammer: this is true, but since a function has truthiness true, so it makes no *semantical* difference.

Comment: C'mon @WillemVanOnsem I was on a call.

Comment: @RicardoTejada: if you are on a call, you should not just dump a question and leave it here. Please [edit] the question with the `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: Well, unexpected calls happen, right? It's edited already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`auto_now=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [**`auto_now_add=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) expects booleans, so `True`, not `datetime.now`, but since a function has by default truthiness `True`, that will also work.

The consequence of `auto_now=True` or `auto_now_add=True` implies that [**`editable=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable) is set to `False` as well, and this means that, by default, the field is no longer in `ModelForm`s nor in the admin.

You can however explicitly list the item as a field in the [**`readonly_fields`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), to ensure that it is displayed, so:

```
from django.contrib import admin


@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        'name',
        'description',
        'brand',
        'creation_date',
        'modified',
        'start_date',
    )
    readonly_fields = ('creation_date', 'modified')
```

Comment: This managed to show creation_date and modified inside the Django admin panel, but current DateTime is not shown https://imgur.com/a/i9c10CD. Should I use something like a default or so? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: @RicardoTejada: since the fields are not editable, you can not add a value. Normally these should also *not* be part of the `ModelAdmin`. Did you specify the `readonly_fields`.,,

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did update the fields `creation_date` and `modified` under the Project class to: `auto_now_add=True` and `auto_now=True` but it's still not displayed

Comment: I have managed to use this solution for my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in the admin.py by `get_readonly_fields` on a model registered to show read only fields. You can [reference here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) and here is an example

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourApp.models import Project

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            # Should return ('created_at', 'created_by') from Project model
            return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        else:
            """
             Add read only fields that you want none superusers
             to read or just return none if not needed
            """
            return ('field_2', 'filed_2',...)

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Comment: Hey there! I keep on getting `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. I'm not entirely sure how to make your implementation